# How get content in block which we get from remote url (parsing)?

Tags: php, parsing, html, file-get-contents

Good day.

i use code:

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://www.whois.com/whois/testtest.com');
```

Full code page whice get **$file** you can see **[here](http://pastebin.com/tQXm0mkt)**

Tell me please how get content in block `<div class="whois_result" id="registryData">....</div>` ?

Comment: there are much better ways to this than scrapeing from others

Comment: @Dagon can said more about it ?

Comment: no more than a minute or two on google, or this site

Comment: Tonight's winner of longest code count.

Comment: half the questions seem to be about how do i steal from others sites, no one does anything original.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes-yes, if show start code only) P.S.: +1 for smile)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of you you scrape the remote page (hint: look at cURL), you need some sort of DOM parser to parse the response.

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true); //Prevents Warnings, remove if desired
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($file);
$node = $dom->getElementById("registryData");
$output = $dom->saveHTML($node);

echo $output;
```